# Crash while releasing in implementation of NSCoding Protocol methods

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

Below is the code I use for unarchiving the data:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSString *resoureItemClassName = NSStringFromClass([ResourceItem class]);
        self.selectedItemClassName=[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"selectedItemClassName"];
        Class class = NSClassFromString(selectedItemClassName);
        id temp = nil;

        if(class)
        {      
            temp = [[class alloc] init];
        }

        if(temp)
        {
            if([temp isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
                self.selectedString = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"selectedString"];;
                self.ID = selectedString;
            }
            else if([selectedItemClassName isEqualToString:resoureItemClassName])
            {  
                DLog(@"Resource item")
            }

            [temp release];                         
        }
        else
        {    
            self.ID = nil;
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

When I release the tempObject, the app crashes. If I do not do it, it is a leak. I tried using the autorelease method. Still then it crashed? What is the solution?

**UPDATE:**

The encoded data in selectedItemClassName is either __NSCFConstantString or __NSCFString. The crash occurs only with __NSCFString and  not with __NSCFConstantString as the class name,

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is the type of the object that is crashing? Does it always crash? Print a `[temp className]` before releasing

Comment: The same problem does not happen with __NSCFConstantString

Comment: not that its going to fix anything but if(temp) is pointless, it all hinges on if(class) anyways.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        NSString *resourceItemClassName = NSStringFromClass([ResourceItem class]);
        self.selectedItemClassName=[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"selectedItemClassName"];
        Class class = NSClassFromString(selectedItemClassName);

        if(class)
        {      
            NSString *stringClassName = NSStringFromClass([NSString class]);
            if([stringClassName isEqualToString:self.selectedItemClassName])
            {
                self.selectedString = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"selectedString"];;
                self.ID = selectedString;
            }
            else if([self.selectedItemClassName isEqualToString:resourceItemClassName])
            {  
                DLog(@"Resource item")
            }
        }
        else
        {    
            self.ID = nil;
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```